# SSIS Как конвертировать string в float, проблема с разделителем

Tags: sql-server, integration-services

Импортирую excel табличку в mssql посредством ssis. В этой табличке float значения, с разделителем точка. Соответственно при импорте данных ssis не понимает что это float и пишет его как string. Если использовать конвертер, то просто вываливается с ошибкой.
Региональные настройки менять не вариант, так как в других реестрах разделитель стоит уже запятая.
Вариант с Replace точки на запятую в реестре до импортирования подходит,
но возможно есть какое нибудь альтернативное решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вариант с Replace точки на запятую в реестре до импортирования не подходит.

Почему? Вполне обычное решение.

Можете убедится, на sql.ru уже выясняли, что в t-sql других способов нет. [Как заставить SQL Server выгружать числовые данные с запятыми вместо точек?](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=446458&msg=4328998)

Comment: У меня в региональных стандартах стоит запятая, а если запустит другой сотрудник, у кого проставлена точка? Как предусмотреть эту ситуацию?

Comment: @viton-zizu, а в чем проблема? После замены запятой на точку, (1) запятая становится точкой. (2) точка остаётся точкой. Таким образом и в (1) и во (2) случае преобразование во FLOAT пройдёт без ошибок.

Comment: @viton-zizu. Т.е. в вашем случае наоборот. Точку меняем на запятую. Запятая остаётся запятой.

Comment: Ок, спасибо! Просто хотелось узнать об альтернативных способах, будем обходится так.